# PHP Form - Simple Form w/o Validation

Tags: php, html, forms

Not sure whats wrong here the error report says line 9, but when I look the code does not match.

The Error Message :
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting '{' in /home/hletf/public_html/mailform.php on line 9**

Forgive the Tables Please.

**HTML FORM CODE :**

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="mailform.php">

   <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
     <tr>
       <td width="48%"><div align="right"><h3>Name:</h3></div></td>
       <td width="52%"><input type="text" name="NAME" id="NAME" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><div align="right"><h3>Email:</h3></div></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><div align="right"><h3>Comment:</h3></div></td>
       <td><textarea name="COMMENT" id="COMMENT" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><div align="right"></div></td>
       <td>
       <input type="image" name="SUBMIT" id="SUBMIT" src="images/submit_button.jpg" width="81" height="23" />
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
             </form>
```

**MAILFORM.PHP :**

```
<?PHP

define('kOptional', true);
define('kMandatory', false);

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
ini_set('track_errors', true);

function DoStripSlashes($fieldValue)  { 
// temporary fix for PHP6 compatibility - magic quotes deprecated in PHP6
 if ( function_exists( 'get_magic_quotes_gpc' ) && get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) { 
  if (is_array($fieldValue) ) { 
   return array_map('DoStripSlashes', $fieldValue); 
  } else { 
   return trim(stripslashes($fieldValue)); 
  } 
 } else { 
  return $fieldValue; 
 } 
}

function FilterCChars($theString) {
 return preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F]/', '', $theString);
}

function CheckEmail($email, $optional) {
 if ( (strlen($email) == 0) && ($optional === kOptional) ) {
  return true;
 } elseif ( eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$", $email) ) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}



if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
 $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
 $clientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$FTGNAME = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['NAME'] );
$FTGEMAIL = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['EMAIL'] );
$FTGCOMMENT = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['COMMENT'] );
$FTGSUBMIT = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['SUBMIT'] );



$validationFailed = false;

# Fields Validations


if (!CheckEmail($FTGEMAIL, kMandatory)) { $validationFailed = true; }



# Redirect user to the error page

if ($validationFailed === true) {

 header("Location: http://www.glustik.com/error.html");

}

if ( $validationFailed === false ) {

 # Email to Form Owner
  
 $emailSubject = FilterCChars("OMG - Test");
  
 $emailBody = "NAME : $FTGNAME\n"
  . "EMAIL : $FTGEMAIL\n"
  . "COMMENT : $FTGCOMMENT\n"
  . "SUBMIT : $FTGSUBMIT\n"
  . "";
  $emailTo = 'James <james@glustik.com>';
   
  $emailFrom = FilterCChars("$FTGEMAIL");
   
  $emailHeader = "From: $emailFrom\n"
   . "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
   . "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n"
   . "Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit\n";
   
  mail($emailTo, $emailSubject, $emailBody, $emailHeader);
  
  
  # Redirect user to success page

header("Location: http://www.glustik.com/thanks.html");

}

?>
```

Comment: Identify line 15, and show which file is throwing the error.

Comment: How about an error message? Or some guidance as to what the problem is.

Comment: Im sorry, it either slipped my mind, or since it didnt match I didnt think it was relavent. I have add the error message above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function with this one :

```
function DoStripSlashes($fieldValue){
    // temporary fix for PHP6 compatibility - magic quotes deprecated in PHP6
    if ( function_exists( 'get_magic_quotes_gpc' ) && get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) { 
        if (is_array($fieldValue) ) { 
            return array_map('DoStripSlashes', $fieldValue); 
        } else { 
            return trim(stripslashes($fieldValue)); 
        } 
    } else { 
        return $fieldValue; 
    } 
}
```